# How to split a csv file using comma(,) if file attributes can also contain comma using shell/awk/perl

Tags: perl, shell, awk

I Need to split a CSV file using comma and output specific fields to some other CSV file. But Input CSV file has a few attributes that can contain comma itself.
Input CSV looks like below.

Input CSV

```
"Bond,newsssss/10172","20100411141114","abc","19530617000000"
"Link","am"an\grew,123\"mn/n","20100411141114","foo"
"20100411141114","foo","am"an","20100411141114"
"am\",an","over18","bob007@bob007.com","20100411141114"
```

Desired output is as below.

output.csv

```
"20100411141114","19530617000000"
"am"an\grew,123\"mn/n","foo"
"foo",20100411141114"
"over18","20100411141114"
```

i am using a following awk command

```
   awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS=","} { print $2 , $4;}' input.csv > ouput.csv
```

But it is giving me following output

```
newsssss/10172","abc"
"am"an\grew,"20100411141114"
"foo",20100411141114"
an","bob007@bob007.com"
```

i thought about using ", as a value to IFS but then that can also be part of input csv as it is user defined file and there are no specific checks to stop user from doing so. Another problem i have is the server where i am going to execute is Solaris and it has only standard awk. is there a way around here to solve this problem?

Comment: That's covered in the [gawk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Splitting-By-Content) - if you have GNU awk.

Comment: @BenjaminW. another problem i have is the server where i am going to execute is Solaris and it has only standard awk

Comment: Use `Text::CSV_XS` if you going to use perl? (why reinvent the wheel?)

Comment: The default awk on Solaris is NOT "standard awk". Quite the opposite - it is old, broken awk which must never be used by anyone. The closest thing to "standard awk" (where "standard"=="POSIX") on Solaris is /usr/xpg4/bin/awk but install GNU awk, gawk, if you can as it has all of the POSIX standard functionality plus many useful extensions.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks mate i have used /usr/xpg4/bin/awk and its working fine for me now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use following perl oneliner

```
perl -ne '@ar = (split /(?<=\w"),/)[1,3]; print @ar,"\n"; ' input.csv
```

> `-n` switch use to through the while loop for a file
>
> `-e` switch for make the command to execute.

Then I used the  [positive look behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for split the comma, where comma is followed by word character (`\w`) and the double quotes `"`.

`(?<=)` For look ahead

`\w` Match the word character

Then I store the element 1 and 3 in an array.

Comment: it is working exactly the same way i wanted. +1 for that. much appreciated. it would be more helpful if you can explain it litlle bit more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk -F'","' -vq='"' '{print q $2,$4}' OFS='","' file
```

**Test:**

```
$ awk -F'","' -vq='"' '{print q $2,$4}' OFS='","' file
"20100411141114","19530617000000"
"am"an\grew,123\"mn/n","foo"
"foo","20100411141114"
"over18","20100411141114"
```

*Note:*
If `$4` is not end field, then use `q` to print `"`

```
awk -F'","' -vq='"' '{print q $2,$4 q}' OFS='","'
```

Comment: this could work very well +1 for answer. But I have another problem the server where i am going to execute is Solaris and it has only standard awk so this is not working well there. it is splitting the values with " directly.

Comment: @fedorqui thanks Man. . its working fine using that path.